# R - Merge two datasets if ALL values per group match

Tags: r, merge, group-by

Say I have two dataframes df1 and df2 as follow:

df1:

```
EmployeeID     Skill
1                A
1                B
1                C
2                B
2                D
2                C
2                F
3                A
3                J
```

df2:

```
Opportunity.ID      Skill
12345               A
12345               B
56788               C
56788               B
56788               F
09988               H
```

What I'm looking to do is to have a new data frame with all the EmployeeID that have **all the skills required for a specific Opportunity.ID**, and not only one of them. This is why a simple merge or left/right join will not be enought. 
In our case, what I would like to have is:

```
Opportunity.ID         Employee.ID
12345                  1
56788                  2
09988                  NA
```

Note that **employee 3 should not be assigned** to opportunity 12345 because **he only has one skill among the two required**.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you tried something ?

Comment: Employee is missing Skill `E` and shouldn't therefore be assigned to Opportunity `56788` (unless you meant an `E` instead of an `F` in `df1`).

Comment: Yes I have tried to do a merge and left join but it is not working since it does the "match" when one of the value is present

Comment: @Jaap you are right, I have edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `dplyr` -

```
df2 %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = "Skill") %>% 
  group_by(Opportunity.ID) %>% 
  mutate(test = ave(Skill, EmployeeID, FUN = function(x) all(Skill %in% x))) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(test != "FALSE") %>% 
  distinct(Opportunity.ID, EmployeeID)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Opportunity.ID EmployeeID
           <int>      <int>
1          12345          1
2          56788          2
3           9988         NA
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better solution, but with the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)-package I came to the following approach:

```
library(data.table)  # load the package
setDT(df1)           # convert 'df1' to a 'data.table'
setDT(df2)           # convert 'df2' to a 'data.table'

df2[, .(EmployeeID = df1[.SD[, .(Skill, n = .N)], on = .(Skill)
                         ][, .(ne = .N), by = .(EmployeeID, n)
                           ][n == ne, EmployeeID])
    , by = Opportunity.ID]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    Opportunity.ID EmployeeID
> 1:          12345          1
> 2:          56788          2
> 3:           9988         NA
> ```

Comment: Hi @Jaap, thanks for your answer. However, when I run this command on my dataset, it appeared to do the matching based on only one Skill. In this case, it would mean that I will have the employees 1,2 and 3 matched to the Opportunity.ID 12345 since they all have the skill A

Comment: @AllanLC No, it does the matching on all Skills. Could you please include example data in your question that reproduces this problem?